# Tomcat Mybatis Database change is not reflected

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, caching, mybatis

I am using tomcat 8.5 and Mybatis to build my web application.
However, weirdly when I change the data in the database directly from the MysqlWorkbench, it is not reflected on my application when executing SQL(sending get request and fetching data). It is reflected when I restart my tomcat server.
I think it is some kind of cache problem, so I disabled cache in my Mybatis configuration.

```
   <settings> 
    <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false" /> 
    <setting name="localCacheScope" value="STATEMENT"/>
  
   </settings>
```

Also, I use sqlsession.clearCache() directly, but it still fetching the old data.

```
public class ProductDao {

private SqlSession sqlSession;

public ProductDao() {
    sqlSession = DbUtil.getSqlSession();
}

public List<Product> getProductsByOrder(String order) {
    sqlSession.clearCache();
    System.out.println("fetching data from server");
    List<Product> productList = sqlSession.selectList("ProductMapper.getProductsByOrder", order);
    System.out.println(productList.get(0).getProductName());
    //sqlSession.clearCache(); it does not work
    return productList;
}
```

Thus, I think that the caching occurs in the Tomcat, but I highly doubt it because
when I get the list of products in the database, then "getProductsByOrder" is called and the "fetching data from the server" is logged.
To be specific, when I change the productName from test1 to test2 in my mysqlWorkBench,
following log `System.out.println(productList.get(0).getProductName());` is still showing the old product name test1.

Comment: Did you "commit" the changes in MySQL Workbench? I've worked with Tomcat and MyBatis  quite a bit and I haven't encountered this issue, except when I forgot to commit in my SQL tool (squirrel sql client).

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, I commit it and checked the result...